# Find decidable sets such that $A$ reduces to $B$ but not vice versa

Tags: reductions, undecidability, polynomial-time-reductions

I am stuck in this problem, so any help is appreciated. The problem asks to show that there exists decidable sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A \leq_{m}^{p} B$ but $B \not \leq_{m}^{p} A$, and that $A$, $B$ and $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ are infinite. Here, $\leq_{m}^{p}$ refers to many-one polynomial time reducibility.

I have a hunch that this may have something to do with letting $A$ be a decidable set such that $A \in \mathsf{EXP}$, but $B \in \mathsf{P}$, so that the reduction cannot be done in polynomial time.

Comment: I would suggest spending some more time on this question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, as a hint, does the solution for this question involve diagonalization?

Comment: In a sense. You wrote the basic idea in your question.